# Fill form with previous values

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form from angular, the user will modify an object with different values, but I have to show him the previous values.

form.html

```
<div class="clr-row">
<form [formGroup]="agreementEditFrm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="clr-col-12">
    <label>Type</label>
    <clr-select-container>
        <select clrSelect class="clr-select" name="libraryItemTypeId" formControlName="agreementType">
            <option></option>
            <option>Option 1</option>
            <option>Option 2</option>
        </select>
        <clr-control-helper>e.g. Select an option</clr-control-helper>
        <clr-control-error>This field is required!</clr-control-error>
    </clr-select-container>
</div>
<div class="clr-col-12" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <label>Reference Number</label>
    <clr-input-container>
        <input clrInput placeholder="Enter value here" name="title" formControlName="referenceNumber"/>
        <clr-control-helper class="clr-subtext">e.g., M-2391</clr-control-helper>
        <clr-control-error>This field is required!</clr-control-error>
    </clr-input-container>
</div>
<div class="clr-col-12" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <label>Effective</label>
    <clr-select-container>
        <select clrSelect class="clr-select" name="libraryItemTypeId" formControlName="isEffective">
            <option></option>
            <option value="Programmatic Agreement">Yes</option>
            <option>No</option>
        </select>
        <clr-control-helper>e.g. Select an option</clr-control-helper>
        <clr-control-error>This field is required!</clr-control-error>
    </clr-select-container>
</div>
<div class="clr-col-12" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <clr-date-container>
        <label>Effective Date</label>
        <input type="date" clrDate name="demo" formControlName="dateEffective">
    </clr-date-container>
</div>
<div class="clr-col-12" style="margin-top: 24px;">
    <clr-date-container>
        <label>Expiration Date</label>
        <input type="date" clrDate name="demo" formControlName="dateExpiration">
    </clr-date-container>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

form.ts

```
agreementSumary: {} = {};
agreementEditFrm = new FormGroup({
    agreementType:  new FormControl('', []),
    referenceNumber:  new FormControl('', []),
    isEffective:  new FormControl('', []),
    dateEffective:  new FormControl('', []),
    dateExpiration:  new FormControl('', [])
});

constructor(private dataService: DataServicesService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.url[1].path
    this.dataService.getProject(this.id).subscribe((rps) => {
        this.agreementSumary = {
            agreementType: rps.agreement.agreementType,
            referenceNumber: rps.agreement.referenceNumber,
            isEffective: rps.agreement.isEffective,
            dateEffective: rps.agreement.dateEffective,
            dateExpiration: rps.agreement.dateExpiration
        }
        let keys = Object.keys(this.agreementSumary);
        let values = Object.values(this.agreementSumary);
        for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            this.agreementEditFrm.controls[`${keys[i]}`].setValue(values[i]);
            console.log(this.agreementEditFrm.controls[`${keys[i]}`].value)
        }
        console.log(this.agreementEditFrm.controls)
    },
    error => console.log(error)
   )
}
```

Both log's log the correct input, but in my form.html only `referenceNumber` is displaying the correct value, the other ones do not display the value from the form.

I'm thinking I'm making a mistake with the data binding, but I'm not sure what's happening.

Comment: If I got your question right, just `this.agreementEditFrm.setValue(rps.agreement);` should work.

Comment: @developer033 what I mean it's that I'm doing something wrong about the binding to the Html, I'm able to set the data to the controls of my form, but only one is displaying in the Html (`referenceNumber`) the other ones even if I got the value in my form, it's not showing it

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.form.setValue() and make sure data you get in this.agreementSumary is valid. For the select tags to set ,the data should passed them should match the value of  any one option.

```
   this.dataService.getProject(this.id).subscribe((rps) => {
        this.agreementSumary = {
            agreementType: rps.agreement.agreementType,
            referenceNumber: rps.agreement.referenceNumber,
            isEffective: rps.agreement.isEffective,
            dateEffective: rps.agreement.dateEffective,
            dateExpiration: rps.agreement.dateExpiration
        }
       this.agreementEditFrm.setValue(this.agreementSumary); 
        console.log(this.agreementEditFrm.controls)
    },
    error => console.log(error)
   )
```

Comment: the problem it's not setting the data in my form, I'm doing that right, the problem is that is not showing in my Html, just `referenceNumber` is displaying